# Requiring Admin Previleges to Change Proxy Settings

Tags: windows, proxy, uac

I have installed a Squid server to allow a whitelist-only internet access to my employees. All of them are using Standard User accounts in Windows 7 Professional.

I changed the proxy settings in their PCs to the Squid server, and everything works as expected.

Now if one of them types "proxy" in the search bar he will be able to disable the proxy and no Admin password will be required like in changing the static IP address or the default gateway.

How to add changing the proxy settings to the admin level to require admin previleges to this section?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. The Browser proxy settings being found and disabled? or the management control of the proxy itself through the domain name "proxy"?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found this and it's doing what I just wanted: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/85238-internet-options-add-remove-connections-tab.html